# A generalization of Feit–Thompson conjecture, for square-free integers

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisibility

Few weeks ago I wondered about if the following conjecture is in the literature or well if it is possible to find a counterexample. I evoke a generalization of a well-known conjecture, I mean the [*Feit–Thompson conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_conjecture) from Wikipedia.

An integer $n>1$ is square-free or squarefree if has no repeated prime factors. For example $n=15$ is squarefree, while than $12$ has repeated prime factors.

**Conjecture.** *There are no distinct square-free integers* $p$ *and* $q$ *(both greater than* $1$*) with* $\gcd(p,q)=1$ *such that* $\frac{p^q-1}{p-1}$ *divides* $\frac{q^p-1}{q-1}$.

> **Question.** What work can be done about the veracity of this conjecture? Since Feit–Thompson conjecture seems a particular case of this, then I'm asking if previous conjecture is in the literature, or well if you've some approach or heuristic about the **Conjecture** or well if it is possible to find a counterexample. **Many thanks.**

I wrote a Pari/GP program and I've tested the **Conjecture**, let's say for the segments of integers $2\leq p,q\leq 2000$. I hope that there were not mistakes and this post is interesting.

Comment: I believe (I don't know this literature) that the companion reference for this post should be Feit, W. and Thompson, J. G., *A Solvability Criterion for Finite Groups and Some Consequences*, Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA 48, 968-970, 1962.

Comment: Many thanks upvoter, I want to dedicate my posts to people suffering the current disease outbreak.

Comment: This is stronger than The Feit-Thompson conjecture only allowing distinct primes $p,q$, nevertheless I did not find a counterexample upto $p,q=5\ 000$

Comment: Great computations! Many thanks @Peter

Comment: I think it can be further generalized.

Comment: Then it is a perfect feedback @Ante ! I edit my posts with the spirit and motivation to share my questions and try get help from the users. If you think that it can be improved feel free to edit your questions. Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: I will think about it, me and @Peter are sometimes in this chatroom so if you need to you can chat with us:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96072/hilberts-hotel

Comment: I suspect that you are more likely to get an answer for this kind of literature-knowledge question from MathOverflow. (Although wait until your bounty runs out to do this.)

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and advice @user1729 . After the bounty ends (I hope in any case contributions before the bounty ends, see in previous comment that an user added great computations/computuational evidence) I am going to consider your comment.

Comment: My belief is that your are right @Masterphile , although I didn't do experiments and I don't know if the following thread of thought is in the literature. I evoke from Feit-Thompson conjecture  the *form* of a divisor function $\sigma_{\alpha}(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n} d^\alpha$ with $\alpha\geq 0$ integer, at the value $n=x^{y-1}$ for *primes* $x$ and $y$. Then using $\sigma_1(n)=\sigma(n)$ we can rewrite Feit-Thompson. Other example (obvious and redundant) to emphasize my words: *there are no distinct prime numbers* $p$ *and* $q$ *such that* $\sigma_0(p^{q-1})$ *divides* $\sigma_0(q^{p-1})$.

Comment: I've asked it with my account MathOverflow MO question **357133**, that is [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357133/a-generalization-of-feit-thompson-conjecture-for-square-free-integers). To the moderator team of MO/MSE, as soon there is feedback about if this question is interesting for MathOverflow, feel free to handle the MSE 3591614 question as you consider it is right (I say this since I never had a cross-posted question).